# Problems with mi WiFi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, lenovo

I would like to ask you for help with my WiFi connection. My problem looks like this:

- After I turn on my laptop or after reboot everything works fine.

But after suspend my WiFi works about 6 minutes and then stops responding. It looks like it's connected but it doesn't respond. It is happening in all networks.

After I turn on/off wifi, it works for the next 6 minutes. After reboot all is fine until the next suspend.

I am on `ubuntu 14.04` and my laptop is lenovo G50-70

when I add this :

```
sudo rfkill list
```

it shows this

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Is there any one can help my ???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lspci&&lsusb`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: Did not give any answer. And gives the wrong question

Answer (score 0):

This happens because this laptop has no wireless hardware switch. Kernel driver can't handle this right. I made a ppa with a patched ideapad-laptop driver. Patch is queued upstream, but it will take time to get into stable kernels. The driver can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop
```

Wireless must work after reboot.